# C++ Template Parameter sizeof Returns Incorrect Result

Tags: c++, templates, sizeof

That way I can find the number of elements in an array. However, when I put this int array as a template as a parameter, the result is not calculated correctly

```
int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int size_arr  =  sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
```

I add an INT Array to the List as a parameter with the type template.

```
template <typename listType, typename arrayX>
 listType  addList(listType e , arrayX array)
{
     int        sizeOf = sizeof(array);
     int        sizeOfperOne = sizeof(array[0]);
     int        arrSize =  sizeOf   /   sizeOfperOne        ;
     cout << "Total Byte :  " << sizeOf << "     BytePerUnit : " << sizeOfperOne << " arrSize : " << arrSize<< endl;
     for (int i = 0; i <  arrSize; i++)
    {
        e.push_back(array[i]);
    }
    return e;
}
```

And the other Template and Method in created to print this List content

```
template    <typename T>
void print(T& t, string name)
{
    typename T::iterator i = t.begin();
    cout << name << "\tMembers  ==>>>   ";
    while (i != t.end())
    {
        if (i == t.begin())
        {
            cout << *i++;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << " - " << *i++;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

---

```
int main() 
{
    int mlArray[] = { 1,2,3,4,5};
    
    list<int>   MasterListe ;
    MasterListe = addList(MasterListe, mlArray);
    cout << "MasterListe SizeOf :    " << MasterListe.size() << endl;
    print(MasterListe, "MasterList      : ");
    return 0;
}
```

> Total Byte :  8  BytePerUnit : 4 arrSize : 2

> MasterListe SizeOf :  2
> MasterList              :       Members ==>>>   1 - 2

Array is filled with numbers 1,2,3,4,5, although 5 units are passed, the return value is 1 and 2.

I may also want to create the list that I am currently using in the INT type from the class below.

```
 list<TradeList>
```

---

```
class TradeList
{
    public:
            int      PosTicket  ;
            strinh   Pairs      ;
            double   OpenPrice  ;
            double   StopLoss   ;
            double   TakeProfit ;
}
```

Believe me, I couldn't find a solution to this through my research.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: [Arrays decay to pointers](/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay) when they are passed like that.  All you have there in `addList` is an `int *`, not an array of `int`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo The code shown seems quite reproducible actually.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Is it possible to write a sample? 
I don't want to get it wrong because of the English translation.

Comment: @cigienThat's nice. I didn't see it.

Comment: int mlArray[] = { 1,2,3,4,5};
 int *ptrArray = mlArray;
  
 list<int> MasterListe ;
 MasterListe = addList(MasterListe, ptrArray);

Comment: That's how I did it, but it didn't happen again.
 listType  addList(listType e , const arrayX*  array)

Comment: It's not strange to ask a quesion again.

Comment: Why do you need an `addList` when there is a generic way to add items to a container?  `std::copy(ptrArray, ptrArray + sizeof(ptrArray) / sizeof(ptrArray[0]), std::inserter(MasterListe, MasterListe.end()));`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie   The sample you wrote had the same result. I'm only getting 1 and 2 output.
Why do I need this? 
I need to update a list of Forex transactions in 5 minutes. I didn't think of a different solution.

Comment: That should be: `std::copy_n(mlArray, std::size(mlArray), std::inserter(MasterListe, MasterListe.end()));` -- There is no need for an extraneous function such as `addList` or a `ptrArray` pointer.

Comment: This code you wrote is working.
Can you use it as List<TradeList> ?
Thank you so much for your reply.

Comment: Update your original post so that we see what `TradeList` is.  Also, C++ is case sensitive -- do you really mean `std::list<TradeList>`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ok , updated now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that arrays decay to pointers, thus the values of `sizeof()` in your template function `addList` actually is attempting to get `sizeof(int *)`.

If all that `addList` does is add items to the `std::list`, there are generic ways to do this without need to create another function.

One way is to use [std::copy_n](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

class TradeList
{
    public:
        int      PosTicket  ;
        std::string   Pairs      ;
        double   OpenPrice  ;
        double   StopLoss   ;
        double   TakeProfit ;
};

int main()
{
    TradeList mlArray[5];
    std::list<TradeList>   MasterListe;
    std::copy_n(mlArray, std::size(mlArray), std::inserter(MasterListe, MasterListe.end()));
    std::cout << MasterListe.size();
}
```

Output:

```
5
```

Comment: Which do you think makes more sense in terms of performance?

Answer (score 2):

Array decays to pointers, if you need the size of array inside template function, you can change your function to below.

```
template <typename listType, std::size_t N, typename arrayX>
listType  addList(listType e , arrayX (&array)[N] )
{
     int        sizeOf = sizeof(array);
     int        sizeOfperOne = sizeof(array[0]);
     int        arrSize =  N;
     cout << "Total Byte : " << sizeOf
          << "     BytePerUnit : " << sizeOfperOne
          << " arrSize : " << arrSize
          << endl;
     for (int i = 0; i <  N; i++)
    {
        e.push_back(array[i]);
    }
    return e;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a waste of time.
Handle the extra operations in the Main method.

```
 template <typename listType, typename arrayX>
 listType  InsertList(listType e, arrayX array, int size)
 {

     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
     {
         e.push_back(array[i]);
     }
     return e;
 }
```

Main Method

```
int main() 
{
    int mlArray[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    list<int> SecondList;
 
    ThirdList=  InsertList(SecondList, mlArray, size(mlArray));
    print(SecondList, "SecondList : ");

    return 0;
}
```